# How to integrate matlab with QT

Tags: qt, matlab, qt4

I want to call matlab from QT 4 (used for UI only in my project)  where i can pass values and read values back from matlab. and also run the .m scripts and then get the results back from matlab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QT is irrelevant here.

You basically want to use the [Matlab Engine](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_external/f29148.html#f26499). You can call Matlab from compiled C++ (for example). You'll probably want to use `engOpen` to start the connection and then `engEvalString` to run scripts.   You may also want to use `engGetVariable`, `mxGetClassID` and `mxGetDimensions` to access the results.

But definitely read the documentation and try it, then come back with more detailed questions.